# Notice: Undefined index: href error

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I tried to programmatically insert few taxonomy terms.

```
$arr = array('term1', 'term2', 'term3', 'term4');
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
$term = new stdClass();
$term->name = $value; 
$term->vid = '5'; 
$term->parent ='122'; 
taxonomy_term_save($term);
}
```

This work nice.After i try to create with hand one more term but i got this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: href in menu_local_tasks() (line 2052 of /includes/menu.inc).
```

The same error i got after i tried to edit any of the taxonomy term added with code.

I clear cache.
Drupal 7.